# Preemptive Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: c, scheduling, cpu-registers, msp430, preemptive

Here is a small preemptive scheduling algorithm for MSP430G2553 Launchpad from @tonyp12 from https://forum.43oh.com/topic/9450-tiny-msp430-preemptive-multitasking-system/

Even though I know the concept of contet switching, this program confuses me a little bit. Can someone explain what he is doing step by step specifically in the below snippets?

```
int* multistack = (int*) __get_SP_register();
  int i=﻿0; while(i<tasks-1﻿)﻿{
    int j = stacksize[i]; if (!j) j = 24;
    multistack -= j;  
    *(multis﻿tack) = (int) taskpnt[++i]﻿﻿﻿;﻿﻿﻿ ﻿﻿﻿        // prefill in PC 
    *(multistack-1) = GIE;                      // prefill in SR
    taskstackpnt[i] = (int) multistack-26;      // needs 12 dummy push words
  }﻿
```

and

```
#pragma vector = WDT_VECTOR 
__raw __interrupt void taskswitcher(void)
{
  asm ("push R15\n push R14\n push R13\n push R12\n"
       "push R11\n push R10\n push R9\n push R8\n"
       "push R7\n push R6\n push R5\n push R4");

  taskstackpnt[taskrun﻿] = __get_SP_register();
  if (++taskrun == tasks) taskrun = 0;
  __set_SP_register(﻿taskstackpnt[taskrun]);
  ﻿
  asm ("pop R4\n pop R5\n pop R6\n pop R7\n"
       "pop R8\n pop R9\n pop R10\n pop R11\n"
      ﻿ "pop R12\n pop R13\n pop R14\n pop R15");
}﻿
```

Thanks. And here is the complete code:

```
#include "msp430.h"
#include "common.h"

//=========================(C) Tony Philipsson 2016 =======================
funcpnt const taskpnt[]={ task1, task2, task3,  // <- PUT YOUR TASKS HERE
}; 
const int stacksize[tasks] = {28};              // a blank value defaults to 24 stack words
//=========================================================================
int taskstackpnt[tasks];
unsigned int taskdelay[tasks];
char taskrun;

int main( void )
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                     // Stop watchdog timer 
  if (CALBC1_8MHZ != 0xff){               // erased by mistake?
    BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_8MHZ;                   // Set DCO to factory calibrate 1MHz  
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_8MHZ;
  } 
  int* multistack = (int*) __get_SP_register();
  int i=0; while(i<tasks-1﻿)﻿{
    int j = stacksize[i]; if (!j) j = 24;
    multistack -= j;  
    *(multistack) = (int) taskpnt[++i]﻿﻿﻿;﻿﻿﻿ ﻿﻿﻿        // prefill in PC 
    *(multistack-1) = GIE;                      // prefill in SR
    taskstackpnt[i] = (int) multistack-26;      // needs 12 dummy push words
  }﻿
  WDTCTL = WDTPW+WDTTMSEL+WDTCNTCL;             // 4ms interval at 8MHz smclk
  IE1 |= WDTIE;
  __bis_SR_register(GIE);
  asm ("br &taskpnt﻿");﻿                          // indirect jmp to first task
}

//============= TASK SWITCHER ISR =============
#pragma vector = WDT_VECTOR 
__raw __interrupt void taskswitcher(void)
{
  asm ("push R15\n push R14\n push R13\n push R12\n"
       "push R11\n push R10\n push R9\n push R8\n"
       "push R7\n push R6\n push R5\n push R4");

  taskstackpnt[taskrun﻿] = __get_SP_register();
  if (++taskrun == tasks) taskrun = 0;
  __set_SP_register(﻿taskstackpnt[taskrun]);

  asm ("pop R4\n pop R5\n pop R6\n pop R7\n"
       "pop R8\n pop R9\n pop R10\n pop R11\n"
       "pop R12\n pop R13\n pop R14\n pop R15");
} 
#include "msp430.h"
#include "common.h"

__task void task1(void){
  P1DIR |= BIT0;
  while(1){
    __delay_cycles(800000);
    P1OUT |= BIT0;
    __delay_cycles(800000);
    P1OUT &=~BIT0;        
  }
}
#include "msp430.h"
#include "common.h"

__task void task2(void){
  P1DIR |= BIT6;
  while(1){
    __delay_cycles(1200000);
    P1OUT |= BIT6;
    __delay_cycles(1200000);
    P1OUT &=~BIT6;        
  }
}
#include "msp430.h"
#include "common.h"
unsigned int fibo(int);

__task void task3(void){
  int temp = 0;
  while(1){
    fibo(++temp);
  }
}
unsigned int fibo(int n){
  if (n < 2)
    return n;
  else
    return (fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2));
}
#ifndef COMMON_H_
#define COMMON_H_
#define  tasks (sizeof(taskpnt)/2)
__task void task1(void);
__task void task2(void);
__task void task3(void);
typedef __task void﻿ (*funcpnt)(void);
#endif
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please explain how much you know about the C language, the MSP430 architecture, and the intrinsic functions used in the above code, and how much of this code you understand, and what you assume it does.

Answer (score 2):

**The first snipped of code initialize all the stacks for the various tasks.**

First saving the PC as the address of the task function (the first instruction):

```
*(multistack) = (int) taskpnt[++i];
```

then it saves the status register with the GIE enabled (needed for correct task switch function):

```
*(multistack-1) = GIE;
```

These two will be restored automatically by reti when the scheduler interrupt will end.

Also the new stackpointer for the task is saved (including space for registries saving):

```
taskstackpnt[i] = (int) multistack-26;
```

**The second snippet is the scheduler interrupt itself.**

The PC and the SR are saved by hardware during interrupt calling automagically. In the interrupt code the registry are saved for current task:

```
asm ("push R15\n push R14\n push R13\n push R12\n"
   "push R11\n push R10\n push R9\n push R8\n"
   "push R7\n push R6\n push R5\n push R4");
```

then the software saves the stack pointer for the current task:

```
taskstackpnt[taskrun] = __get_SP_register();
```

and get the next task stack pointer index:

```
if (++taskrun == tasks) taskrun = 0;
```

then restore the new task stack pointer:

```
__set_SP_register(taskstackpnt[taskrun]);
```

and pop the registries saved in stack:

```
 asm ("pop R4\n pop R5\n pop R6\n pop R7\n"
   "pop R8\n pop R9\n pop R10\n pop R11\n"
   "pop R12\n pop R13\n pop R14\n pop R15");
```

The PC and SR for the new task are restored by interrupt's reti.

The new task is ready to go!